# 'Delete' action occurring twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have a strange situation with the delete action of my files controller.

```
Started GET "/files/35/delete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-27 01:13:51 -0500
Processing by FilesController#delete as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `files` WHERE (`files`.`id` = 35)
SQL (0.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/files
Completed 302 Found in 713ms

Started GET "/files/35/delete" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-27 01:13:52 -0500
Processing by FilesController#delete as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
...leads to error
```

The controller action:

```
@file = @company.files.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
@file.destroy
flash[:notice] = "Your file was deleted successfully."
redirect_to files_url
```

Routes:

```
resources :files do
  member do
    get 'delete_ask'
    get 'delete'
  end
end
```

Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@file = @company.files.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
if @file
    @file.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Your file was deleted successfully."
else
    #file was deleted
    flash[:notice] = "Patience: you only need to press delete once" 
end
redirect_to files_url
```

You can `rescue` from errors:

```
@file = @company.files.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
    @file.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Your file was deleted successfully.
#rescue from error
rescue 
    flash[:notice] = "Patience: you only need to press delete once" 
    redirect_to files_url
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this happens due to double submit of the request. Try to prevent the double submits either at the client side through javascript or on the server side (which will require some more effort than the client side but more robust).